# Centering with auto layout to work on all screen sizes?

Tags: xcode, layout

I'm going crazy over xcodes auto layout!! Really need som help now. I made an app with 8 buttons (only to be viewed in lanscape) that I want to look good (or ok) on iPhone 4, 5 and 6/6+.

I want the title and the buttons to be centered horizontally on all devices. I would be nice if the size increased when viewed on iphone 6/6+ but its not necessary. I tried to put the buttons in a seperate view but I only managed to get it to look good on 4 and 5 that way.

(I'm using xcode 6.1)
Click on the link to see the structure of my layout:
http://groupnoir.com/test.html

Please help!

Comment: Set some horizontal spacing constraint between each button of a line and set a "equal widths" constraints with each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a lot, but I have found this to work. Create 1 large view that will hold all the buttons. You need to pin edges to the Superview (Editor > Pin). Add 8 views inside that view and evenly space with auto layout (using equal widths or pin to desired width). You should pin all 4 sides of all the smaller views to the larger view and it's neighbors. You can add a button inside each of the 8 views align horizontal/vertical in container (Editor > Align).